# Interrupt Arduino if voltage is below some level or a switch which will not allow current to pass across if no sufficient voltage

Tags: arduino, ac, interrupts, voltage-measurement

I'm a very beginner in electronics. Actually from software field. With some craze started with Arduino. What am trying to implement is a simple interrupt mechanism which will interrupt Arduino if AC voltage if under a predefined level (don't need to measure the voltage). For example if mine is a 220 volt circuit and if it's below 180v it should interrupt on an interupt pin on Arduino.
 I'm not looking for a complicated system like measuring the voltage and making the decision. Instead of something like a resistor or what ever which will not allow the current to flow if under some range like above. But please remember it's on AC supply. Or is there is any simple component like MOSFETs or bjts which only allow the current flow if base voltage is above a point. I'm a humbly mentioning my knowledge of these electronic components are very very less..

Comment: If you can actually find one, because they've been pretty much obsolete for a while, an old unregulated DC plug-pack / wall wart that uses a transformer is an easy safe way to get a low voltage. They tend to be larger and heavier than modern ones that use a switch-mode supply.

Answer (score 7):

Given you are trying to detect line voltage, your level of electronics knowledge, and that this will be connected to a arduino, you really need to use isolation of some sort.

Here is a example:

[image]

The diodes full-wave rectify the AC line.  At your threshold of 180 VAC, the rectified DC will be 253 V.

The DC voltage is divided down by R1 and R2.  The voltage drop of the LED and the B-E junction of the transistor are used as the reference voltage.  These are rough and temperature-dependent, but it doesn't sound like you need high accuracy.  When the divided voltage gets to about 1.8 V, the LED in the opto is turned on.  R3 limits the LED current to a safe but sufficient level.

When the opto is turned on, it pulls low on OUT.  Otherwise, R4 pulls OUT high.  OUT being low therefore indicates the presence of AC roughly above the threshold.

Make sure the parts can withstand up to 400 V on the DC supply.  That leaves some margin above what *should* happen.  The 400 V needs to be considered when choosing the diodes, C1, R1, R3, and Q1.  It might be simpler to implement R1 and R3 as several smaller resistors in series.

At the threshold, the LED current is about 350 µA.  The output of the opto needs to sink 330 µA.  That means you need the opto to have a CTR (current transfer ratio) of about 1.  The opto shown has a minimum guaranteed CTR of 3, although at higher LED current.  Nonetheless, there is sufficient margin that this should work reliably.

Remember that everything on the left side of the opto is at dangerous voltages.  This section must be well insulated and sealed so nothing can accidentally touch it.

Comment: Isn’t the LED current a bit low? With R1 and R3 at 1MΩ you’ll only get 2*0.25mA of current. The current transfer diagram in the FOD817D datasheet doesn’t even start at such a low current (starts with CTR=0.8 at 1mA).  The LED can survive up to 50mA so why not lower the resistor value to 220kΩ (1.15+0.25mA of current) or so? Of course the downside is that you might have to increase the C1 value to avoid excessive ripple.

Comment: @Mich: The datasheet I have says the CTR is 3 at 5 mA.  It has a graph for the FOD817 showing a CTR of .75 a 1 mA.  The FOD817D seems to have about 6x higher CTR, so even with the degredation due to low current, the CTR should still be sufficient.  However, decreasing R3 to around 500 kOhms is fine as long as you deal with the power dissipation properly.  With the DC at 350 V due to high line, the dissipation of R3 would then be 1/4 W.  You could use a 1/2 W resistor, or string maybe 3 0805 1/8 W resistors in series.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "off the shelf" solution for that, you'll need to measure the voltage of your AC line.
I recommend a peak hold circuit consisting of a voltage divider (R1,R2), a rectifier (BR1) with a cap (C1) that stores the potential.
R4 is inserted to make the cap capable to discharge and follow a voltage drop on your mains line. You'll have to adjust the Time constant for your needs. (Tau = R4*C1).
The transformer is there to decouple your circuitry from the mains, because it can become dangerous for you and your circuit to be connected directly if some part of the circuit fails.
You can also adjust the values of the voltage divider to better suit your needs, eg. to get a better dynamic range.
Also there are other peak detect circuits, but i think this one is alright :D

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUQePW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some more thoughts on this:
Best use a step down transformer so you don't have a high voltage on your secondary side, but remember that your current will rise, the lower you go with your voltage.
To counteract this you need to increase the impedance of your primary coil, which is important, because you don't want to blow any fuses in your home.

Comment: Since my knowledge is very poor in these elements, it will be really helpful if you can specify some values of codes of the components in the above circuit in the case of 230v AC

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be **very** careful measuring mains AC voltage. You ideally should use some isolated circuitry to measure the voltage.

In any case the ATMega328P (MCU on an Arduino) has an Analogue Comparator module. There are two pins connected to the analogue comparator - AIN1 and AIN0. The comparator can be configured to trigger an interrupt when the voltage at AIN1 drops below the voltage at AIN0 or rises above it.

By using one pin as a reference voltage (you can also use the internal 1.1V bandgap reference if you wish to save a pin), and then connected the other pin to the voltage you wish to measure via a potential divider circuit you can get an interrupt when a voltage drops below some arbitrary value as set by the potential divider.

For example if you use the 1.1V bandgap, and you has a potential divider of two 10k resistors (just an example), then the voltage at the comparator input would drop below the bandgap reference if the voltage at the input of the potential divider drops below 2.2V.

Theoretically you can do this to measure mains voltage, however you would first have to rectify the voltage to get a DC level to measure, using an RC circuit to filter out ripple and get an average value. I would then drop the voltage using a potential divider to a safe level and feed that through an **isolated** amplifier for safety purposes. The output of the amplifier can then feed a second potential divider which would drive the analogue comparator input.

Alternatively you could isolate and step down using a transformer from the mains to some lower voltage, then rectify and filter, and potential divider to the analogue comparator. That would provide a much simpler isolation. You could steal a toroidal transformer from an old AC-AC power supply.

Comment: Sorry. Since my very basic knowledge in electronics, by voltage divider you mean a transformer?

Comment: @sforsandeep See [Olin Lathrop's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/323628/59864), which uses a voltage divider.